# Proving that $l^2$ is a vector space - how is the following true?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In part of my lecture notes, the lecturer states that: $$l^2 := \big\{ x = (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \ \ \big| \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^2 < +\infty \big\}$$ is a vector space since: $$|x_i + y_i|^2 \leq 2|x_i|^2 + 2|y_i|^2$$ I understand why, if that is true, then $l^2$ is a vector space (since scalar multiplication is not hard to justify and if you take the sum over $i$ of the above inequality then you can see that the right hand side consists of terms which are already contained in $l^2$).

However I do not understand why that inequality is true. It might be easy to prove that it's true in the case of $2$, but what about for general $p$? For example, can I then say: $$|x_i + y_i|^p \leq p|x_i|^p + p|y_i|^p$$ in order to prove that $l^p$ is a vector space? If so then how do I know that's true (it might not be, I'm just eager to know)?

Thanks for any advice you can give me!

Comment: You may be interested in [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: I have thought about this but I thought that this would come after in establishing that it is a normed vector space, as opposed to simply a vector space, which is what I'm trying to show now

Comment: My intuition tells me that this kind of inequality can be proved via calculus somehow. Is this a common way to justify that they are vector spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The case $p=2$:

$|x_i+y_i|^2=|(x_i+y_i)^2|=|x_i^2+2x_iy_i+y_i^2| \le |x_i|^2+2|x_i||y_i|+|y_i|^2 \le 2|x_i|^2+2|y_i|^2$.

The last inequality is valid since $2|x_iy_i| \le |x_i|^2+|y_i|^2$ (Binomi !)

The general case: in this case the correct inequality is

$|x_i+y_i|^p \le 2^{p-1}(|x_i|^p+|y_i|^p)$

Comment: Hang on, maybe I'm being thick here but you claim that the last is true via binomial theorem. In the case $n=2$, for two values $x$ and $y$ we have: $(x^2 + y^2) = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$. How exactly do you go from that to your conclusion?

Comment: The inequality $a^2+2ab+b^2 \le 2a^2+2b^2$ is equvalent to $2ab \le a^2+b^2$. And this is equivalent to $0 \le a^2-2ab+b^2$. Now you only have to see that $a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $\;\lvert x_i+y_i\rvert^p \le 2^{p-1}(\lvert x_i\rvert^p+\lvert y_i\rvert^p)$ comes from *Jensen's inequality* for the convex function $t\mapsto t^p\;$ ($p>1)$:
$$\biggl(\frac{\lvert x+y\rvert}2\biggr)^p\le\biggl(\frac{\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert}2\biggr)^p \le\frac{\lvert x\rvert^p+\lvert y\rvert^p}2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to prove that the $l^p$ spaces are vector spaces without such knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

in general $l^2 = \{ (x_n)_n, x_n \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is proven to be a Hilbert space  by defining the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)
$$\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_n x_n y_n$$ which is bilinear and hence $$\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x+y,x+y \rangle=\langle x,x \rangle+\langle y,y \rangle+\langle y,x \rangle+\langle x,y \rangle = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+ 2\langle x,y \rangle$$
Now $|\langle x,y \rangle| \le \|x\| \|y\|$ is the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), that is obvious when writing that $y = ax+z, a =\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|^2}, z = y-ax, \langle x,z\rangle = 0$  so that $\|y\|^2 = |a|^2\|x\|^2+ \|z\|^2$ and $|\langle x,y\rangle| = |a| \|x\|^2 \le \|x\|\, \|y\|$

and overall
$$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2 \langle x,y\rangle < \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2 \|x\| \, \|y\| = (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2$$

Comment: if you consider instead the $\mathbb{C}$ vector space $l^2 = \{ (x_n)_n, x_n \in \mathbb{C}\}$, you have the hermitian product $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_n x_n \overline{y_n}$ which is $\mathbb{R}$ bilinear, and hence the proof follows the same lines